# Could we assume without loss of generality that all coefficients are positive?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\alpha$ be an element in the group algebra $\mathbb CG$ of a torsion-free group $G$. Assume that, as an operator acting on $\ell^2(G)$, $\alpha$ is positive. Does there exist $\beta\in\mathbb CG$ such that coefficients of $\beta^*\alpha\beta$ are all positive real numbers?

Comment: When $G$ is commutative (for example $\mathbf Z$), you have the Fourier transform that translates your question to an elementary question on functions on the circle. You will easily find counterexamples in that case.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle: Could you please give me one of such counterexamples?

Comment: Seen as a function on the circle, $\alpha(z) = |z-1|^2$. Or any positive trigonometric polynomial vanishing at $z=1$.

Comment: Because the sum of the coefficients (=Fourier coefficients here) of $\alpha |\beta|^2$ is the value of $\alpha |\beta|^2$ at $z=1$, so is $0$.